# How do I protect cells at given time (given in same row) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've read that a Google script may be the solution, but given that I am not at all familiar with coding/VBA, I need some help.

Let's say my sheet looks like this (Sorry for the 'norwegian' date-format):

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 14:00 | Value W | Value X |
| 03.01.2021 15:00 | Value Y | Value Z |

When the current time hits the value in column A, the values in column B and C should be automatically protected, so that only I/selected users can edit them later on.

The list goes on downwards for almost 50 rows. I have multiple users in this sheet, and everyone can edit the values in column B and C.

Any awesome helpers out there?

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*To protect a range in Sheets refer to the following [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).*

### Explanation

The attached documentation explains how to apply protection to a range through the UI version of Sheets. This protection prevents the non-selected users from modifying a particular range. This way, you can choose to make the range modifiable by you or more users.

In case you need to implement a variation in the editing permissions on that range, you can use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). In this, there are tools such as [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) that allow you to execute a function at a specific time. In addition, the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) has a function called [protect()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect) to enable and disable protection to a particular range.

### References

- [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Range: protect](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect)

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I'm still far away as I do not know the script language or any VBA for that matter. Would you be able to set up the script as needed?